# Microprocessor vs discrete FET clock speed

Tags: microprocessors

How do microprocessors achieve such high clock speeds when discrete FETs can only achieve approx 20MHz? Do they have a large number of parallel sequential logic systems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered posting this question to [Electronics.Stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single transistors can switch much faster than the clock of a microprocessor. One example: 45 GHz transistors by [Infineon](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf/rf-transistors/ultra-low-noise-sige%3ac-transistors-for-use-up-to-12-ghz/channel.html?channel=db3a30432b16d655012b1e9ec92d5b2d).

Usually there are somewhere around 15-25 transistors in series in the longest path of a modern CPU, so the clock speed is at least an order of magnitude less than the switching speed of the individual transistors.

Comment: So why not just create a microprocessor with these? I don't see why the losses would be so high (an order of magnitude simply because of being in series).

Comment: Also, is an RF transistor a high-speed switching transistor or something else? I thought the main limitation of transistor switcging is the time taken for currents to change so how was this addressed?

Comment: The normal assumption in clocked hardware design is that within each clock cycle all data starts in registers is transformed by some logic and stored in new register. More details on registers on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Classical_positive-edge-triggered_D_flip-flop) - it also discusses setup and hold times

The more logic you can use between the registers the more meaningful operations you can do up to a certain point. The ~20 gate delays per clock seem to be the sweet spot for processor design.

Comment: So how is such great switching speed attained when (I believe) the time taken for currents to change limits switching to around about 20 MHz?